# Define multiple Require.js modules in single JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two JavaScript modules that I need to use in my web application. And I'm using Require.js to handle my module dependencies. As per Require.js tutorials I've went through, only one module can define in single JavaScript file. Because Require.js keeps those dependencies using the file name.

Eg:

`require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/jquery-latest.min"
    }
});`

So as far as I know we can define one module per page. I have around 20 modules in my web application. Do I have to create separate JS file for each module ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: sorry for the less infomation. question edited.

Comment: This questions changed a lot (in good) since it was closed. I still think you should test and search a little more before asking but in case you still need the answer and you can't get this question reopened, ask a new different one.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. I agree with what dystroy said, but the close reason is no longer applicable.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do. Where is the value for `this` supposed to be coming from? How do you expect to use those two modules?

Comment: Question changed. @dystroy Thanks for bare with me